# IOS live stream f4m file

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming

How to play f4m file in ios swift code

f4m file return

```
<manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">
<id>flussonic_media</id>
<streamType>live</streamType>
<bootstrapInfo profile="named" id="bootstrap1" url="bootstrap"/>
<media streamId="stream1" url="hds/tracks-1,2/" bitrate="726" bootstrapInfoId="bootstrap1">
<metadata>
AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQMADWF1ZGlvY2hhbm5lbHMAQAAAAAAAAAAADGF1ZGlvY29kZWNpZABAJAAAAAAAAAANYXVkaW9kYXRhcmF0ZQBAZWAAAAAAAAAPYXVkaW9zYW1wbGVyYXRlAEDncAAAAAAAAAZoZWlnaHQAQHUAAAAAAAAADHZpZGVvY29kZWNpZABAHAAAAAAAAAANdmlkZW9kYXRhcmF0ZQBAhrAAAAAAAAAFd2lkdGgAQILAAAAAAAAAAAk=
</metadata>
</media>
</manifest>
```

this url for testing

> http://streamer11.elementssys.com:8080/demo/Hadath/manifest.f4m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f4m is an XML based manifest file for FLV video. FLV is Flash Live Video and iOS doesn't support the Flash file format and probably never will.